# Is there a way to manually render Table in ant design?

Tags: antd

According to [Table documentation of Ant Design](https://ant.design/components/table/), it seems that there is no way to render Table manually, e.g.:

```
// Possible
<Table dataSource={dataSource} columns={columns} />

// Impossible
<Table>
  <Row>
    <Col></Col>
  </Row>
</Table>
```

Am I misunderstanding Ant Design Table? Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Definitely not possible and not the intended design by the developers. However, what is it that you want to achieve with the manual way that the abstracted way can't do?

Answer (score 0):

There is no meaning to do it manually.

But if you don't like the design of it & you want to modify its design, then yes, you can override those. For that, you can use ant-d classes to override. Like -

```
.ant-table {
  border: 1px solid #28293D;

  .ant-table-column-sorter-up.active,
  .ant-table-column-sorter-down.active {
    color: #186497;
  }
}

.ant-table-thead th {
  color: #6B6D7D!important;
  font: 14px/19px Roboto, sans-serif !important;
}
```